# can only save last record in array cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp

I cant save all the multiple records for some reason as I just get the last record saved  . I have tried options like atomic and validate but it doesn't solve the issue. I don't get an error message as to why it isn't allsaving so I am wasting time just guessing.

What happens is that I save the last record only of about 7 records so it does save but just once only. I am only saving in 1 table with no associations. With no error output I don't know what to do

```
 $alltimesheetLessons = $this->TimesheetLessons->newEntities( $timesheetLesson, ['validate' =>  false]);


                foreach ( $alltimesheetLessons as $key => $entity) {
               // debug($entity->toArray());
                  $this->TimesheetLessons->save($entity, ['atomic' =>  false]);

                }//for
```

//here is a sample of 2 records

```
'tutor_id' => (int) 12,
'subject_id' => (int) 16,
'lesson_plan' => 'q1)Evidence:',
'lesson_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

    'time' => '2016-09-20T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

},
'period_start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

    'time' => '2016-09-19T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

},
'period_end_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

    'time' => '2016-10-02T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

},
'lesson_id' => (int) 18913,
'submit_date' => '2016-10-02',
'invoice' => '49',
'term_id' => (int) 0,
'start_time' => '10:00 ',
'end_time' => '11:00 ',
'student_name' => 'jjde',
'class_year' => (int) 8,
'subjectname' => 'Maths: Year 7 - 10',
'makeup_lesson' => false,
'makeup_lesson_expired' => false,
'makeup_expiry_date' => null,
'lesson_inactive' => false,
'cancelled_by' => '',
'schedule_rec' => false,
'forefit' => (int) 0,
'cancelled_date' => null,
'tutoring_type_id' => (int) 1,
'payrate' => (float) 20,
'lesson_duration' => (float) 1,
'amount' => (float) 20
```

]

```
 \src\Controller\LessonsController.php (line 2590)

[
    'tutor_id' => (int) 12,
    'subject_id' => (int) 16,
    'lesson_plan' => 'q1)EvidimplestvformHomeWork:',
    'lesson_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

        'time' => '2016-09-20T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'period_start_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

        'time' => '2016-09-19T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'period_end_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

        'time' => '2016-10-02T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'lesson_id' => (int) 18914,
    'submit_date' => '2016-10-02',
    'invoice' => '49',
    'term_id' => (int) 0,
    'start_time' => '11:00 ',
    'end_time' => '12:00 ',
    'student_name' => 'Jhj',
    'class_year' => (int) 8,
    'subjectname' => 'Maths: Year 7 - 10',
    'makeup_lesson' => false,
    'makeup_lesson_expired' => false,
    'makeup_expiry_date' => null,
    'lesson_inactive' => false,
    'cancelled_by' => '',
    'schedule_rec' => false,
    'forefit' => (int) 0,
    'cancelled_date' => null,
    'tutoring_type_id' => (int) 1,
    'payrate' => (float) 20,
    'lesson_duration' => (float) 1,
    'amount' => (float) 20
]

 foreach ($data as  $key => $item):



                $timesheetLesson[$key]['tutor_id']=$item['tutor_id'];
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['subject_id']=$item['subject_id'];
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['lesson_plan']=$item['lesson_plan'];
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['lesson_date']=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['lesson_date']));
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['period_start_date']=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startdate));
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['period_end_date']=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($enddate));

                $timesheetLesson[$key]['lesson_id']=$item['id'];
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['submit_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['invoice']=$invoice;

                $timesheetLesson[$key]['term_id']=$item['term_id'];
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['start_time']=date('h:i ', strtotime($item['start_time']));
                $timesheetLesson[$key]['end_time']=date('h:i ', strtotime($item['end_time']));


              endforeach;
```

Comment: Please `pr($this->request->data)` first. Also, you need to show your template code where you have written the Form Helper.

Comment: there is no $this->request->data as I am creating the data in  the controller. i am not using form data

Comment: Okay, but there has to be an array. I think the array is `$timesheetLesson`. Please share the structure of this array.

Answer (score 0):

`$result =` will overwrite on each iteration of the array; leaving it populated with the last of the loop. To build a new array you can use:

```
$result[] =
```

which will populate the $result array with each.

Comment: no that doesnt work. if i get rid of result it still does work. i will update the OP

Comment: look at the OP now as this just has the save command and no $result but it still saves the last record only

Comment: ok now i am panicking as I need to get this working today and with no way to detect any errors I dont know what to do!

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the results to the array `$result`. Like this:

```
$result[] = ...;
       ^^
```

Or this:

```
array_push($result, $value_pushed);
```

Comment: forget the $result , i deleted it. It only saves the last record.

Comment: so what variable did you store the last record to?

Comment: I will update the above post to show how I entered the data. At the bottom of the OP you can see this. The result is 7 records

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in that there is a build rule that is stopping a 0 entry for a field being entered. Even with validate is false the buildrule is still active